# Branch.io Cordova SDK not generating links

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap, branch.io

I am trying to integrate Branch.io into my mobile app, mostly for the purpose of tracking and rewarding referrals.  I have the plugin mostly working, but it is failing at the most important part, generating the links.  The app successfully initiates Branch, creates a Universal Object and I get a confirmation alert every time the app opens.  It also successfully opens the share sheet when I click the share button and fills in the message text, but it doesn't contain the link.  I've also noticed that the Branch.io dashboard is not recognizing that I've integrated the SDK.  I am using PhoneGap build 6.2.0 and Cordova Branch SDK version 2.6.0

Here is my the Branch snippet of my config.xml

```html
<plugin name="branch-cordova-sdk" spec="^2.6.0" /><!-- If available via Cordova registry; consider changing to an NPM reference. -->
<branch-config>
  <branch-key value="key_live_xxxx" />
  <uri-scheme value="xxxx" />
  <link-domain value="xxxx.app.link" />
  <ios-team-release value="xxxx" />
</branch-config>
```

And here's a screen shot of the alert after creating a universal object and of the share sheet

[Universal Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WLVb.png)

[Share Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zzQx.png)

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: this is unusual! Could you [take a look in your logs](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking#compiling-show-console-logs) and see if there are any error messages that might be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

It Is the issue with PGB Service

i had same issue with my project also... i am taking build using phonegap build service. universal object is initializing but the link is not generating.. in ios 9.3 the Share sheet comes. but there is no link . in ios 10 even Share sheet is not opening

Try Using Mac with cordova my issue solved

check this link ..

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2290461